# Use getSupportFragmentManager() Inside PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

I have my custom **`ConfigActivity`** which extends PreferenceActivity (from `android.preference.PreferenceActivity`). The layout for this activity contains a `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"...`. Inside this layout, I need to programmatically add/replace a couple of other Fragments I have created that extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

However, Eclipse says:

`The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ConfigActivity`.

I tried replacing it for just `getFragmentManager()`, but the following call:

`ft.add(R.id.fHeader, new MyCustomFragment());`

results in the following error:

`The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MyCustomFragment)`

Is my only option to NOT use my custom Fragments that extends the support library's Fragment class inside ConfigActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to make your activity extend FragmentActivity or some subclass of FragmentActivity to work with Fragments if you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.
Other option can be to make your minimum sdk version set to 12 and check your code without using support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Usual `Activity` do not have `FragmentManager`. If you want to use `Fragment` in your `Activity`, you should use `FragmentActivity` which is in support libs.
Because android is open source, you can use the code in `PreferenceActivity`, and make a `MyPreferenceActivity extends FragmentActivity`. Hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: Good idea but this can't be achieved considering that PreferenceActivity extends ListActivity so adding code of FragmentActivity is not enough.